# ¿Cómo insertar comillas simples en base de datos MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Cuando un usuario ingresa comillas simples o dobles en un formulario que tengo, los datos no se ingresan en la base de datos. Por lo que estuve leyendo las comillas simple sirve para delimitar las sentencias.

Y la solución mas rápida que encontré fue reemplazar las comillas simples con otro carácter como se muestra en la siguiente linea de código:

```
$vCampo1 = str_replace("'", '\\\'', $vCampo1 );
```

Fuente:
http://notasweb.com/articulo/php/utilizar-comilla-simple-en-mysql.html

El problema es que tarde o temprano alguien necesitará ingresar información con comillas simples en la base de datos y reemplazar el carácter por otro no es una opción.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes escaparlas con `\` como ya te han indicado.

También puedes usar la función [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Esta función no solo te escapará las comillas, sino que también lo hará con el resto de caracteres especiales como

> NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", y Control-Z

Usarla es muy sencillo:

```
<?php
$cadena = "Cadena ' con ' comillas simples";
$cadenaEscapada = mysqli_real_escape_string($cadena);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias amigo! ya implemente esa función en mi sistema y funciona muy bien.

Answer (score 3):

solo necesitas comentarla de la siguiente manera:

```
\'
```

y en tal caso que tengas que arreglar el texto:

```
$text = str_replace("'", '\'', $text);
```

estas practicas no son recomendadas pueden provocar vulnerabilidades llamadas injection code sql. lo recomendado es que esta sean limpiadas.

Comment: Excelente gracias por la contribución, si tienes razón me decidí por usar otras funciones que ademas de resolver el problema servirán para evitar inyecciones de código.

Comment: de nada escoje una respuesta que se haya acercado mas a tu pregunta. saludos.

Answer (score 2):

En `php` se soluciona ejecutando una consulta `sql` preparada, mediante las herramientas que nos proporciona la capa de abstracción de la librería `PDO`. Como lo he dicho, esta librería es una capa de abstracción que nos permite trabajar con más de 12 motores de base de datos diferentes, y es una mejora sustancial de la seguridad en comparación con `mysqli` (D:'). El método `PDO::bindParam()` se encarga de *escapar* todo carácter especial en la manipulación de `strings` para evitar métodos de inyección `SQL`, reemplazando *apuntadores* especiales que dejemos en la definición de nuestra consulta con la variable que contenga nuestro string con carácteres especiales.

Un buen ejemplo de un caso real me sucedió con el nombre de mi región, "Región del Libertador General Bernardo **O'Higgins** Riquelme", que lleva una comilla simple.

Con `PDO` quedaría más o menos así:

```
<?php

// Instanciando el objeto PDO al crear la conexión:

$miPdo = new PDO("mysql:host='nombre_servidor';dbname='nombre_db';charset=utf8",'usuario','pass');

// Representación de la variable que contendrá la cadena con el carácter especial

$region = "Región del Libertador General Bernardo O'Higgins Riquelme";

// Aludiremos una tabla con un solo campo para este ejemplo

$sql = "insert into tabla_regiones values(:ARG);";

// Iniciamos la preparación de la sentencia

$sttmnt = $miPdo->prepare($sql);

// >Insertamos el texto de nuestra variable que contiene el carácter
// especial en la consulta sql de la siguiente forma:
//
// 1) Debemos indicar cuál será el apuntador que debemos reemplazar (:ARG)
//
// 2) Debemos indicar con qué VARIABLE lo vamos a reemplazar
// ----***IMPORTANTE: el método bindParam() solo acepta VARIABLES
// ----para asociar a la consulta. Si intentamos escribir directamente en la
// ----definición del método obtendremos un error y la consulta no computará***
// 3) Por último debemos especificar qué tipo de dato estamos asociando para que
// ----bindParam() sepa cómo manipularlo. En este caso, al ser un string debemos
// ----declarar el manejador PDO::PARAM_STR

$sttmnt->bindParam(':ARG', $region, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Finalmente ejecutamos:

$sttmnt->execute();

?>
```

-Recomiendo que se pasen por la [documentación de PDO en el [sitio oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.pdo.php), si no lo conocen les va a cambiar la vida.

Answer (score -1):

Para mi la solucion mas sencilla es codificarlas en [base64encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php) y luego recuperarla con [base64decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-decode.php) para imprimirlo

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mas sobre esta respuesta?

Comment: pues si se codifica con la función base64_encode() la cual convierte un texto a caracteres en base 64 y los recuperas con la función base64_decode()

Comment: ejemplo:
$var = "hola mundo ,'como estan'";
$var = base64_encode($var);
por lo que var ahora es = aG9sYSBtdW5uZG8gLCdjb21vIGVzdGFuJw==
y si lo recuperas que igual al $var original

Comment: Te recomendaria mirar [answer]. Tu respuesta no tienen nada que ver con la pregunta.. aca se pregunta como escapar esos caracteres para meterlos a una base de datos. Tu respuesta, ademas de escueta, no dice como hacer eso, con estas funciones que planteas. por esto te dieron el -1.. No estas respondiendo la pregunta...